# Hangfire With Autofac in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I have following configuration in startup.cs but I am getting error although I have installed `Hangifre.Autofac` nuget package and configured.

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates
>   that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by
>   a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web
>   integration always request dependencies from the
>   DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime,
>   never from the container itself.

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


            //if (AppConfigHelper.PlatformEnvironment == PlatformEnvironment.LocalHost)
            builder.RegisterType<NLogLogger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            //else
            //builder.RegisterType<SentryLogger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            //builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(configuration);

            // REGISTER CONTROLLERS SO DEPENDENCIES ARE CONSTRUCTOR INJECTED
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();

            //These lines warm up dlls and load into memory for automatic regisration
            var r = new ReplyRepository(null);
            var s = new BankService();

            builder.RegisterModule(new SelfRegisterModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new RepositoryModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new EFModule());


            builder
                   .RegisterType<ApplicationOAuthProvider>()
                   .As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
                   .PropertiesAutowired() // to automatically resolve IUserService
                   .SingleInstance(); // you only need one instance of this provider

            builder.RegisterType<SellutionUserStore>().As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>>().InstancePerBackgroundJob().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<SellutionUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerBackgroundJob().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<SellutionRoleManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerBackgroundJob().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<SellutionSignInManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerBackgroundJob().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InstancePerBackgroundJob().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register<IDataProtectionProvider>(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerBackgroundJob().InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<TicketDataFormat>().As<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();

            builder.RegisterType<TicketSerializer>().As<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>();
            builder.Register(c => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("Sellution360").Create("ASP.NET Identity")).As<IDataProtector>();

            builder.RegisterType<CurrencyRatesJob>().AsSelf().InstancePerBackgroundJob();

            // BUILD THE CONTAINER
            var container = builder.Build();

            Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);
            JobActivator.Current = new AutofacJobActivator(container);


            // REPLACE THE MVC DEPENDENCY RESOLVER WITH AUTOFAC
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

            // Set the dependency resolver for Web API.
            var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;

            // Set the dependency resolver for MVC.
            var mvcResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(mvcResolver);


            // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac MVC middleware.
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacMvc().UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseAutofacWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration).UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); ;

            IocManager.Instance.IocContainer = container;

            ConfigureAuth(app);
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();

            Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
            app.UseHangfireDashboard();
            app.UseHangfireServer();

            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<CurrencyRatesJob>(j => j.Execute(), Cron.Minutely);
        }
```

**CurrencyRatesJob.cs**

```
 public class CurrencyRatesJob
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IBusinessTypeService _businessTypeService;

        public CurrencyRatesJob(ILogger logger, IBusinessTypeService businessTypeService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _businessTypeService = businessTypeService;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            var types = _businessTypeService.GetBusinessTypes();
            _logger.Log("waqar");

        }
    }
```

Comment: that question was not answered tooo

Answer (score 1):

`InstancePerBackgroundJob` creates `Per Macthing Life Time` scope with `BackgroundJobScope` tag. But `Per Request` instances are resolved in another lifetimescope with `Request` tag. So when you try resolve `Per Request` object in `BackgroundJobScope` life time, it gives error. It says, you can only resolve me in `Request` lifetime not in root or another. So you should use `Per Life Time Scope` instead of `Per Request`.

So these `Per Life Time Scope` registered objects will get parents lifetimescope. If it's singleton they will be in root. If their parent lifetimescope is request they will live with this request scope. It's same for `InstancePerBackgroundJob` they will live in `BackgroundJobScope` life time scope.

And it's good for background objects has another life timescope if they use request lifetime scope your objects can be disposed when request finishes. Also if they are in root scope they will never dispose.

Comment: so what do you think using this is not good practice? `InstancePerBackgroundJob` https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Autofac/blob/e223d3e95e80a9e242e36db82a8993fbe63a3505/HangFire.Autofac/RegistrationExtensions.cs

Comment: I didn't check all code but as I can see `InstancePerBackgroundJob` creates `InstancePerMatchingLifeTimeScope`  with `BackgroundJobScope` and manages objects in that scope. It's good because request lifetimescope can finish while background job is still going. I will edit my answer.